# How to unload a package without restarting R

Tags: r, package, r-faq

I'd like to unload a package without having to restart R (mostly because restarting R as I try out different, conflicting packages is getting frustrating, but conceivably this could be used in a program to use one function and then another--although namespace referencing is probably a better idea for that use).

`?library` doesn't show any options that would unload a package.

There is a [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536036/rmlist-ls-doesnt-completely-clear-the-workspace/3537342#3537342) that `detach` can unload package, but the following both fail:

```
detach(vegan)
```

> Error in `detach(vegan)` : invalid `name` argument

```
detach("vegan")
```

> Error in `detach("vegan")` : invalid `name` argument

So how do I unload a package?

Comment: @Iterator: A library is a location where you find packages.  (They are not synonymous.) `.libPaths()` gives you the paths to all the libraries on your system.

Comment: @Richie: Thanks.  I get that in the R context, but I feel that R usage overloads or makes ambiguous the term `library` in two ways: 1 - it's not the same use of `library` as elsewhere, and 2 - the term is used in `library()` to load...not a library, but a package.

Comment: @Iterator You are right. This was the answer I needed, and when googling I used "opposite of `require`" or "undo `library`" because that is how I typically load, erm, "packages". So titling it properly makes the question more correct but also harder to find.

Comment: I usually use standard R `detach`command without any external packages. It has worked for me, but there are many things I don't know.

Answer (score 836, accepted):

Try this (see `?detach` for more details):

```
detach("package:vegan", unload=TRUE)
```

---

It is possible to have multiple versions of a package loaded at once (for example, if you have a development version and a stable version in different libraries). To guarantee that all copies are detached, use this function.

```
detach_package <- function(pkg, character.only = FALSE)
{
  if(!character.only)
  {
    pkg <- deparse(substitute(pkg))
  }
  search_item <- paste("package", pkg, sep = ":")
  while(search_item %in% search())
  {
    detach(search_item, unload = TRUE, character.only = TRUE)
  }
}
```

Usage is, for example

```
detach_package(vegan)
```

or

```
detach_package("vegan", TRUE)
```

Comment: @hadley Indeed.  The unquoted version doesn't seem to work in the latest version of R.  I've updated kohske's answer to reflect your solution.

Comment: @AriB.Friedman, is there an way to detach several packages at once? When I load say `Hmisc` it also loads `survival` and `splines` is there a way to unload that groups together?

Comment: @EricFail Sounds like a new question?

Comment: `> detach("package:MASS", unload=TRUE)
Error in detach("package:MASS", unload = TRUE) : invalid 'name' argument `

Comment: If you get an invalid 'name' argument error, add character.only=TRUE.

Comment: > detach("package:kriging", unload=TRUE, character.only=T)
    Error in detach("package:kriging", unload = TRUE, character.only = T) : 
  invalid 'name' argument.  
However @rstober solution does work!

Comment: A while later, but wondering if @EricFail got a solution? I want to remove multiple unrelated packages at once. Is this possible in one command, or do I need to repeat the same command for each package?

Answer (score 126):

You can also use the `unloadNamespace` command, as in:

```
unloadNamespace("sqldf")
```

The function detaches the namespace prior to unloading it.

Comment: In case @kohske's solution also didn't work for you, this worked for me

Answer (score 45):

You can uncheck the checkbox button in RStudio (packages).

[image: RStudio packages pane]

Comment: It is worth adding that this results in a `detach("package:packageToUnload", unload=TRUE)` command being executed and is no different to [already proposed solution.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6979989/1655567)

Comment: Also, the box isn't checked if the package was loaded using rstudio install & restart (bug?). But you can just check and uncheck it.

Answer (score 10):

I tried what kohske wrote as an answer and I got error again, so I did some search and found this which worked for me (R 3.0.2):

```
require(splines) # package
detach(package:splines)
```

or also

```
library(splines)
pkg <- "package:splines"
detach(pkg, character.only = TRUE)
```

Comment: What error do you get? Because it works for me (R 3.1). And the second solution is the same @koshke's answer, only without unload (so the package namespace is not unloaded).

Comment: I got the same error. the point is I gave the same solution as @Kohske but with different package name. it simply means that if you use the package: then it should work fine, but if you don't use that, you will get the same error as in the question. ;)

Comment: Wait... so you tried to unload a package that wasn't even loaded? And you're surprised you got an error?

Comment: @Gregor Would you please read again everything before pressing downvote button?!!! the function require() and library() almost does the same (atleast in this case), so the package is already loaded !! I'm not responsible for you lack of information!!

Answer (score 10):

When you are going back and forth between scripts it may only *sometimes* be necessary to unload a package. Here's a simple IF statement that will prevent warnings that would appear if you tried to unload a package that was not currently loaded.

```
if("package:vegan" %in% search()) detach("package:vegan", unload=TRUE)
```

Including this at the top of a script might be helpful.

I hope that makes your day!

Answer (score 9):

`detach(package:PackageName)` works and there is no need to use quotes.

Answer (score 7):

Another option is

```
devtools::unload("your-package")
```

This apparently also deals with the [issue of registered S3 methods that are not removed](https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/pull/1001) with `unloadNamespace()`

Comment: I've been trying to detach formula.tools. This is the only approach that worked for me, at least in terms of reverting the effects of said package on as.character. Thanks!!

Answer (score 6):

You can *try* all you want to remove a package (and all the dependencies it brought in alongside) using `unloadNamespace()` but the *memory footprint* will still persist. And no, `detach("package:,packageName", unload=TRUE, force = TRUE)` will not work either.

From a fresh new console or `Session > Restart R` check memory with the `pryr` package:

```
pryr::mem_used()

# 40.6 MB   ## This will depend on which packages are loaded obviously (can also fluctuate a bit after the decimal)
```

Check my `sessionInfo()`

```
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17763)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Canada.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Canada.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_Canada.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=English_Canada.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.1   pryr_0.1.4       magrittr_1.5     tools_3.6.1      Rcpp_1.0.3       stringi_1.4.3    codetools_0.2-16 stringr_1.4.0   
[9] packrat_0.5.0
```

Let's load the `Seurat` package and check the new *memory footprint*:

```
library(Seurat)
pryr::mem_used()

# 172 MB    ## Likely to change in the future but just to give you an idea
```

Let's use `unloadNamespace()` to remove everything:

```
unloadNamespace("Seurat")
unloadNamespace("ape")
unloadNamespace("cluster")
unloadNamespace("cowplot")
unloadNamespace("ROCR")
unloadNamespace("gplots")
unloadNamespace("caTools")
unloadNamespace("bitops")
unloadNamespace("fitdistrplus")
unloadNamespace("RColorBrewer")
unloadNamespace("sctransform")
unloadNamespace("future.apply")
unloadNamespace("future")
unloadNamespace("plotly")
unloadNamespace("ggrepel")
unloadNamespace("ggridges")
unloadNamespace("ggplot2")
unloadNamespace("gridExtra")
unloadNamespace("gtable")
unloadNamespace("uwot")
unloadNamespace("irlba")
unloadNamespace("leiden")
unloadNamespace("reticulate")
unloadNamespace("rsvd")
unloadNamespace("survival")
unloadNamespace("Matrix")
unloadNamespace("nlme")
unloadNamespace("lmtest")
unloadNamespace("zoo")
unloadNamespace("metap")
unloadNamespace("lattice")
unloadNamespace("grid")
unloadNamespace("httr")
unloadNamespace("ica")
unloadNamespace("igraph")
unloadNamespace("irlba")
unloadNamespace("KernSmooth")
unloadNamespace("leiden")
unloadNamespace("MASS")
unloadNamespace("pbapply")
unloadNamespace("plotly")
unloadNamespace("png")
unloadNamespace("RANN")
unloadNamespace("RcppAnnoy")
unloadNamespace("tidyr")
unloadNamespace("dplyr")
unloadNamespace("tibble")
unloadNamespace("RANN")
unloadNamespace("tidyselect")
unloadNamespace("purrr")
unloadNamespace("htmlwidgets")
unloadNamespace("htmltools")
unloadNamespace("lifecycle")
unloadNamespace("pillar")
unloadNamespace("vctrs")
unloadNamespace("rlang")
unloadNamespace("Rtsne")
unloadNamespace("SDMTools")
unloadNamespace("Rdpack")
unloadNamespace("bibtex")
unloadNamespace("tsne")
unloadNamespace("backports")
unloadNamespace("R6")
unloadNamespace("lazyeval")
unloadNamespace("scales")
unloadNamespace("munsell")
unloadNamespace("colorspace")
unloadNamespace("npsurv")
unloadNamespace("compiler")
unloadNamespace("digest")
unloadNamespace("R.utils")
unloadNamespace("pkgconfig")
unloadNamespace("gbRd")
unloadNamespace("parallel")
unloadNamespace("gdata")
unloadNamespace("listenv")
unloadNamespace("crayon")
unloadNamespace("splines")
unloadNamespace("zeallot")
unloadNamespace("reshape")
unloadNamespace("glue")
unloadNamespace("lsei")
unloadNamespace("RcppParallel")
unloadNamespace("data.table")
unloadNamespace("viridisLite")
unloadNamespace("globals")
```

Now check `sessionInfo()`:

```
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17763)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Canada.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Canada.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_Canada.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=English_Canada.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] tools_3.6.1       stringr_1.4.0     rstudioapi_0.10   pryr_0.1.4        jsonlite_1.6      gtools_3.8.1      R.oo_1.22.0      
 [8] magrittr_1.5      Rcpp_1.0.3        R.methodsS3_1.7.1 stringi_1.4.3     plyr_1.8.4        reshape2_1.4.3    codetools_0.2-16 
[15] packrat_0.5.0     assertthat_0.2.1
```

Check the *memory footprint*:

```
pryr::mem_used()

# 173 MB
```

[Link to screen-cast demonstration](https://twitter.com/MattOldach/status/1217595535844106240)

Answer (score 5):

Note also that you can only use `unload()` once. If you use it a second time without rerunning `library()`, y'll get the not very informative error message *invalid 'name' argument*:

```r
library(vegan)
#> Loading required package: permute
#> Loading required package: lattice
#> This is vegan 2.5-6
detach("package:vegan",  unload=TRUE)
detach("package:vegan",  unload=TRUE)
#> Error in detach("package:vegan", unload = TRUE): invalid 'name' argument
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add an alternative solution. This solution does not directly answer your question on *unloading* a package but, IMHO, provides a cleaner alternative to achieve your desired goal, which I understand, is broadly concerned with avoiding name conflicts and trying different functions, as stated:

> mostly because restarting R as I try out different, conflicting packages is getting frustrating, but conceivably this could be used in a program to use one function and then another--although namespace referencing is probably a better idea for that use

## Solution

Function [`with_package`](http://withr.r-lib.org/reference/with_package.html) offered via the [`withr`](http://withr.r-lib.org/index.html) package  offers the possibility to:

> attache a package to the search path, executes the code, then removes the package from the search path. The package namespace is ***not*** unloaded, however.

## Example

```
library(withr)
with_package("ggplot2", {
  ggplot(mtcars) + geom_point(aes(wt, hp))
})
# Calling geom_point outside withr context 
exists("geom_point")
# [1] FALSE
```

`geom_point` used in the example is not accessible from the global namespace. I reckon it may be a cleaner way of handling conflicts than loading and unloading packages.

Answer (score 1):

Just go to OUTPUT window, then click on Packages icon (it is located between **Plot and Help** icons). Remove "**tick / check mark**" from the package you wanted be unload.

For again using the package just put a "**tick or Check mark**" in front of package or use :

```
library (lme4)
```

Comment: Not unless you have your own custom library path. It doesn't show up under "Packages" so you have to do the above methods

Answer (score 1):

Connected with @tjebo answer.

TL;DR
Please use `pkgload:::unload` instead of `devtools::unload` as they are the same function (1 to 1) and `pkgload` is a much lighter package (nr of dependencies). `devtools` simply reexporting the `pkgload:::unload` function.

Unfortunately `devtools` is a huge dependency (as `devtools` has a lot of own dependencies), which is more development stage targeted. So if you want to use the `unload` function in your own package or you care about library size please remember to use `pkgload:::unload` instead of `devtools::unload`. `devtools` simply reexporting the `pkgload:::unload` function.

Please check the footer of the `devtools::unload` function to quickly confirm the reexport or go to the [github repo](https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/blob/697e8d353634373314d04966fe8b8ee46c39983e/R/pkgload.R#L20)

```
> devtools::unload
function (package = pkg_name(), quiet = FALSE) 
{
    if (package == "compiler") {
        oldEnable <- compiler::enableJIT(0)
        if (oldEnable != 0) {
            warning("JIT automatically disabled when unloading the compiler.")
        }
    }
    if (!package %in% loadedNamespaces()) {
        stop("Package ", package, " not found in loaded packages or namespaces")
    }
    unregister_methods(package)
    unloaded <- tryCatch({
        unloadNamespace(package)
        TRUE
    }, error = function(e) FALSE)
    if (!unloaded) {
        unload_pkg_env(package)
        unregister_namespace(package)
    }
    clear_cache()
    unload_dll(package)
}
<bytecode: 0x11a763280>
<environment: namespace:pkgload>
```