# Detach several packages at once

Tags: r, package

Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6979989/1305688) I am looking for a way to detach several packages at once.

When I load say Hmisc,

```
# install.packages("Hmisc", dependencies = TRUE)
require(Hmisc)
```

`R` also loads `survival` and `splines`. My question is if there is a way to unload that group together?

I currently do something like this,

```
detach(package:Hmisc, unload = T) 
detach(package:survival, unload = T) 
detach(package:splines, unload = T)
```

I tried,

```
detach(package:c('Hmisc', 'survival', 'splines'), unload = T)
```

…

Comment: I would be very cautious about group detaching, because it's always possible that you have some **other** package in use which also depends on one of the subordinate packages.  Sort of like the near-impossibility of figuring out which Windows DLLs can safely be removed when uninstalling some app :-( .

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, thank you for your thoughtful comment.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft `detach` does check for dependences and will refuse to detach packages that are required by others in use. You can override this by `force=TRUE`, but that's on your own head, of course.

Comment: @HongOoi -- thanks.  I skimmed right over that part.  Sorry.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Another option:

```
Vectorize(detach)(name=paste0("package:", c("Hmisc","survival","splines")), unload=TRUE, character.only=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 5):

`?detach` explicitly rules out supplying a character vector (as opposed to scalar, ie more than one library to be detached) as its first argument, but you can always make a helper function. This will accept multiple inputs that can be character strings, names, or numbers. Numbers are matched to entries in the initial search list, so the fact that the search list dynamically updates after each detach won't cause it to break.

```
mdetach <- function(..., unload = FALSE, character.only = FALSE, force = FALSE)
{
    path <- search()
    locs <- lapply(match.call(expand=FALSE)$..., function(l) {
        if(is.numeric(l))
            path[l]
        else l
    })
    lapply(locs, function(l)
        eval(substitute(detach(.l, unload=.u, character.only=.c, force=.f),
        list(.l=l, .u=unload, .c=character.only, .f=force))))
    invisible(NULL)
}

library(xts) # also loads zoo

# any combination of these work
mdetach(package:xts, package:zoo, unload=TRUE)
mdetach("package:xts", "package:zoo", unload=TRUE)
mdetach(2, 3, unload=TRUE)
```

The messing with `eval(substitute(...` is necessary because, unless `character.only=TRUE`, `detach` handles its first argument in a nonstandard way. It checks if it's a name, and if so, uses `substitute` and `deparse` to turn it into character. (The `character.only` argument is misnamed really, as `detach(2, character.only=TRUE)` still works. It should really be called "accept.names" or something.)

Comment: Thanks. Feel guilty as I should have read the `?detach` more carefully. Again, thank you for your answer.

Comment: @EricFail No reason to feel guilty.  It's a good question, and the complexity of the answer indicates it's not trivial.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why `detlist<-c('Hmisc','survival','splines'); lapply(detlist, function(k) detach(k,unload=true))`  does not work?  The help page says arguments which are strings are acceptable to `detach` .  (each argument is a one-element string, rather than a vector of characters if I read it right)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I don't understand why so much trouble for a vectorization.

Comment: @Ferdinand.kraft Just being complete, I guess. Besides, being able to detach by numeric index is nice.

Answer (score 2):

To answer my own question to Hong's answer:

```
detlist<-c('Hmisc','survival','splines')

lapply(detlist, function(k) detach( paste('package:', k, sep='', collapse=''), unload=TRUE, char=TRUE))
```

Works just fine.  The sorting function at the top of `base::detach` is a bit wonky, but using `character.only=TRUE`  got me thru just fine.

Answer (score 2):

To delete **all** currently attached packages:

```
lapply(names(sessionInfo()$otherPkgs), function(pkgs) detach(paste0('package:',pkgs),character.only = T,unload = T,force=T))
```