# Why does base::detach validate name inputs the way it does?

Tags: r

After working my way thru  [Detach several packages at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17548385/detach-several-packages-at-once/17554425#17554425) ,  I now wonder if there is a reason the following validation code in `base::detach` is the way it is, or if there's a bug?

(the function itself is `detach(name, pos = 2L, unload = FALSE, character.only = FALSE,
       force = FALSE)` )

```
if (!missing(name)) {
        if (!character.only) 
            name <- substitute(name)
        pos <- if (is.numeric(name)) 
            name
        else {
            if (!is.character(name)) 
                name <- deparse(name)
            match(name, search())
        }
        if (is.na(pos)) 
            stop("invalid 'name' argument")
```

It seems to me that, whether or not the "character.only" argument is set, it would be better to test `is.character(name)`  prior to risking running `substitute()` on the `name` value.  The documentation does not explicitly say that you MUST set `character.only=TRUE` when `name` is a string.
So, before I go off and submit a bug/enhancement request, is there a solid reason for the validation to be the way it is?

Edit: to comment on mnel's response, here's my test example.

```
Rgames> detlist<-c('Hmisc','survival','splines')
Rgames> library(Hmisc)
 Rgames> debug(base::detach)
Rgames> base::detach(detlist[1])

# skipped the startup stuff.

Browse[2]> 
debug: if (!character.only) name <- substitute(name)
Browse[2]> name
[1] "Hmisc"
Browse[2]> 
debug: name <- substitute(name)
Browse[2]> 
debug: pos <- if (is.numeric(name)) name else {
    if (!is.character(name)) 
        name <- deparse(name)
    match(name, search())
}
Browse[2]> name
detlist[1]
Browse[2]> 
debug: if (!is.character(name)) name <- deparse(name)
Browse[2]> 
debug: name <- deparse(name)
Browse[2]> deparse(name)
[1] "detlist[1]"
```

So you see the problem.  My input variable is a valid name, but failure to set `character.only` to `TRUE`  causes an undesired `deparse` to take place, and `match(name, search())` fails for obvious reasons.
It just seems to me that it would be easier for the user if `is.character` were checked first, albeit inside a `tryCatch` to deal with the situation mnel describes.   Two reasons: 1) it's more "user friendly" if `detach` doesn't even need a `character.only` argument, and 2)  the documentation at present doesn't warn that the user **must** set `character.only==TRUE` when the `name` argument is an object containing a character string (but not, I believe if it's a just plain string.  Either detach(package:Hmisc) or detach("package:Hmisc") work, but as my example shows, not a reference to the same string).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a matter of not risking evaluating the `name` argument unless you know it is character only.

Note that `help('detach')` describes the `name` argument as

> This can be an unquoted name or a character string but not a character vector. If a number is supplied this is taken as pos.

`is.character` will evaluate its argument whereas substitute will not. If `name` is not a character string , it will be an unquoted string (such as `package:stats`). If you were to test `is.character(x = package:stats)`, this will try to evaluate `package:stats` (i.e a call to `` `:`(package,stats) ``.  This would not be good (and will return an error or something nonsensical, depending on whether you have values for `package` and `stats` available on your search path).

using `character.only`, means that `substitute` will be called (which won't evaluate the argument), but will return an object of `language` type (if the original were an unquoted name) or a character string (if it were a character string originally). Whatever the outcome, `name` can be `deparsed` to create the required character string.

You can trace what is happening by creating a function with a well placed call to `browser`

eg

```
d <- function (name, pos = 2L, unload = FALSE, character.only = FALSE, 
          force = FALSE) {

  if (!missing(name)) {
    browser()
    if (!character.only) 
      name <- substitute(name)
    pos <- if (is.numeric(name)) 
      name
    else {
      if (!is.character(name)) 
        name <- deparse(name)
      match(name, search())
    }
    if (is.na(pos)) 
      stop("invalid 'name' argument")

}
  return(list(name, pos))
}

# called using an unquoted string.

d(package:stats, pos = 2L)
# Called from: d(package:stats, pos = 2L)
# Browse[1]> n
# debug at #7: if (!character.only) name <- substitute(name)
# Browse[2]> str(name)
# Error in str(name) : object 'package' not found
# Browse[2]> n
# debug at #7: name <- substitute(name)
# Browse[2]> n
# debug at #9: pos <- if (is.numeric(name)) name else {
# if (!is.character(name)) 
#   name <- deparse(name)
# match(name, search())
# }
# Browse[2]> str(name)
# language package:stats
# Browse[2]> n
# debug at #12: if (!is.character(name)) name <- deparse(name)
# Browse[2]> n
# debug at #12: name <- deparse(name)
# Browse[2]> n
# debug at #14: match(name, search())
# Browse[2]> n
# debug at #16: if (is.na(pos)) stop("invalid 'name' argument")
# Browse[2]> n
# debug at #16: NULL
# Browse[2]> str(name)
# chr "package:stats
# Browse[2]> Q

d('package:stats', pos = 2L)
# Called from: d("package:stats", pos = 2L)
# Browse[1]> n
# debug at #7: if (!character.only) name <- substitute(name)
# Browse[2]> n
# debug at #7: name <- substitute(name)
# Browse[2]> n
# debug at #9: pos <- if (is.numeric(name)) name else {
# if (!is.character(name)) 
#   name <- deparse(name)
# match(name, search())
# }
# Browse[2]> str(name)
# chr "package:stats"
# Browse[2]> Q
```

---

Edit in light of edited question.

Perhaps the way `name` is described in the help file should be consistent with the definition of 'package`in`require`&`library`(which have similar methods of dealing with`name`and`character.string` style arguments

i.e

> the name of a package, given as a name or literal character string, or
>   a character string, depending on whether character.only is FALSE
>   (default) or TRUE).

The current definition in `help('detach')` uses `character string` to imply a literal character string containing the name of the item on the search path you wish to `detach` and  `character vector` to define a character vector which contains a character string that  is the name of the item on the search path you wish to `detach`.

I changing the definition in `help('detach')` to

> This can be an unquoted name or a  literal character string. If `character.only == TRUE` then a character vector of length 1 may be supplied. 
>   If a number is supplied this is taken as pos.

or similar may be helpful.

Comment: Hi, please see my edited question which I hope addresses your explanation as well.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft -- see my edited answer. Perhaps a documentation patch could be supplied to make it consistent with `?require`

Comment: `character.only` is misnamed, as I mentioned in my reply to the OP's linked question. It should really be `reject.names` or something similar. We're kind of stuck with it now, though.

Comment: Sounds good to me.  I agree a slight mod to the documentation page would be helpful.