# Remove/detach a package in a R session

Tags: r, dplyr

My question is some packages share the same function name. How can I tell R which package that I want to use this function from?

I tried to load the package that I wanted to use again in the code but it still did not work. My case is the `select` in `MASS` and `dplyr`. I want to use `dplyr` but the error is always `unused argument`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `::` operator:

```
iris %>%
  head(n = 3) %>%
  dplyr::select(Sepal.Length)
```

See [here](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/ns-dblcolon.html) for details.

Or detach MASS ala [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6979917/how-to-unload-a-package-without-restarting-r).