# Why does calling dyn.load in a for loop crash my R session?

Tags: r, dll, rcpp, tmb

R (3.3.2, Windows 7) crashes after about 1000 iterations of `dyn.load()` being used in a for loop. This does not happen in Ubuntu. This behaviour is observed for `dll` files created from `Rcpp` and `TMB` code, but I don't think it is related to either of these packages. The crash message is:

```
Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
Application Name:   rsession.exe
Application Version:    1.0.136.0
Application Timestamp:  583f5668
Fault Module Name:  testRcppRepeatDynLoad.dll
```

The following is a mimimal reproducible example on my computer:

First, create an `Rcpp` package called `testRcppRepeatDynLoad` (in Rstudio, create package in new directory, select 'create package with Rcpp'.). Building the package with `CTRL-SHIFT-B` creates a `dll` file in the `src` folder, which we will load using `dyn.load`.

This code crashes the R session after 1050 iterations:

```
while (i < 2000) {
    i = i + 1
    print(i)
    dyn.load('src/testRcppRepeatDynLoad.dll')
    dyn.unload('src/testRcppRepeatDynLoad.dll')

}
```

The same thing happens for a `dll` file created by `TMB::compile`.

Comment: "Doctor doctor it hurts when I do that.".  "Then don't do it".

Comment: There is no question here.  If we do not know what is in that DLL, and why on Mother Earth you think you would need to load and unload repeated (not something _Writing R Extensions_ suggests you should assume to be capable of) then there is nothing we can do.  See [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example-aka-mcve-minimal-complete-and-ver).

Comment: Some possibly relevant info in this [QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26691878/must-r-packages-unload-dynamic-libraries-when-they-unload)

Comment: Hi Dirk, sorry if the op wasn't clear, but the dll is whatever results from building the package made using `Rcpp.package.skeleton`. That is what the rstudio option create new package with rcpp does. https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486088-Using-Rcpp-with-RStudio?mobile_site=true

Comment: Ok. Then show me where Writing R Extensions, or any other R manual, suggests you can load and unload 2k times.  Some of us are debating whether you can even cleanly unload _once_.

Comment: Also show where the Rcpp suggests you should manually call `dyn.load()`.

Comment: Dirk, I read the link that @BrodieG pointed out and am starting to understand that there may be an issue with the unload process. As for your questions regarding `Rcpp`, I hope I have been clear in the OP that I do not think that this issue is related to `Rcpp` or `TMB`. For the purposes of making a reproducible example (i.e. build a `dll`), I assumed that more people will be able to build a `Rcpp` package dll rather than a `TMB` one. I will edit the question to include the `TMB` example since your comments seem to suggest that I should not use a `Rcpp` package dll to test `dyn.load`...