# package cannot be unloaded in R: cannot install package

Tags: r, fedora, bioconductor

I am trying to install a package in R, but cannot get around the following error.

What is going on? :(

I am running Fedora 20, R 3.2

```
 biocLite("monocle")
    BioC_mirror: http://bioconductor.org
    Using Bioconductor version 3.0 (BiocInstaller 1.16.5), R version 3.2.0.
    Installing package(s) 'monocle'
    trying URL 'http://bioconductor.org/packages/3.0/bioc/src/contrib/monocle_1.0.0.tar.gz'
    Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 332309 bytes (324 KB)

    downloaded 324 KB

    installing *source* package ‘monocle’ ...
    R
    inst
    preparing package for lazy loading
    Error in unloadNamespace(package) : 

    namespace ‘plyr’ is imported by ‘reshape2’, ‘ggplot2’, ‘scales’ so cannot be unloaded
    Error in library(pkg, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE, lib.loc = lib.loc) : 

    Package ‘plyr’ version 1.8.1 cannot be unloaded
    ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘monocle’
    removing ‘/home/user/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.2/monocle’
```

Comment: It's trying to unload `plyr` but you have other packages loaded that are preventing it from doing so - I'm not exactly sure why it's trying to unload `plyr`, but maybe try unloading `reshape2`, `ggplot2`, and `scales` and see if you can install `monocle`?

Comment: Thanks, how can I unload those other packages?

Comment: as per http://stackoverflow.com/a/6979989/743568, `detach("package:reshape2", unload=TRUE)` and so on.

Comment: Does it help to start R with the option --vanilla, `R --vanilla` ? Perhaps you have a .Rprofile or .RData file that is causing plyr and other packages to be loaded during installation.

Answer (score 39):

I resolved this by restarting R.

Comment: I always restart R before installing new packages to avoid this situation. In RStudio/Windows, the shortcut is CTRL-SHIFT-F10.

Comment: Restarting R worked for me too! 
It's to do with the order in which the packages are loaded, generally, the most recently loaded package wins. 
`library(conflicted)` may be helpful in such scenarios, it allows you to choose which function to use https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2018/06/conflicted/

Answer (score 10):

looks like `monocle` is trying to unload and install `plyr` again but it cant because other packages namely `ggplot2`, `scales` and `reshape2` has dependency on `plyr`. Please remove these packages using

```
remove.packages("ggplot2")
remove.packages("reshape2")
remove.packages("scales")
```

and finally

```
remove.packages("plyr")
```

try installing `monocle` again now.

`Monocle` does depends on `plyr`

> Depends   R (>= 2.7.0), HSMMSingleCell(>= 0.101.5), Biobase, ggplot2 (>=
>   0.9.3.1), splines, VGAM (>= 0.9-5), igraph (>= 0.7.0), plyr

on `monocle` homepage http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/monocle.html

Comment: I wish that would solve it! I've tried it several times, but still get the same error once I go back and try to install Monocle... even if all the packages are uninstalled.

Comment: is your package `BiocInstaller` out dated..because in my RStudio while installing its printing 

`trying URL 'http://bioconductor.org/packages/3.1/bioc/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/monocle_1.2.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 756322 bytes (738 KB)
downloaded 738 KB` while in your its downloading a previous version of `monocle`

Answer (score 8):

I was getting the same error for `MASS` package.

Below command used to remove that package.

```
remove.packages("MASS")
```

Tried freshly below commands and it worked.

```
install.packages("MASS")
library(MASS)
```

Answer (score 1):

After you uninstall the packages, quit() and restart R again