# Locating package by not-exported function method

Tags: r, find, package

A situation that often comes up on SO, is packages having overwritten functions causing unexpected errors in packages that rely on certain function definitions (for example `MASS::negative.binomial` and `GLMMadaptive::negative.binomial` has different argument, which causes some dependent packages to fail).

If the function clashing is exported from the package, a fix that doesn't require closing and opening `R` can often be achieved as

```
pck <- find("negative.binomial")
if(length(pck) > 0){
   suppressWarnings(sapply(unlist(pck), function(x) 
                           detach(x, unload = TRUE, 
                                  force = TRUE, character.only = TRUE))
}
if(length(find("negative.binomial")) == 0)
   cat("Succes!\n")
```

(credits to the popular question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6979917/how-to-unload-a-package-without-restarting-r), for the idea.)

But in the case that a function or a method of a function is not exported, eg. `lme4:::influence.merMod` and `car:::influence.merMod`, `find` won't find the function

```
>library(lme4)
>library(car)
>find("influence.merMod")
character(0)
```

Given only the method of function as a string, how would one `find` the `attached` packages which includes a specific none-exported function or method?

Comment: A not-exported function can't be masked because a package needs to import it explicitly and a user can't access it without prefixing the package.

Comment: Might be the case, my question still stands. How would one locate packages which include functions or methods that are not exported, only by using a similar method to `find(...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getAnywhere` will find all occurrences and then we can extract the names from the structure it returns.

```
unique(sub(".*[ :]", "", getAnywhere("influence.merMod")$where))  
## [1] "lme4" "car"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
library(lme4)
library(car)

fun <- "influence.merMod"
p <- loadedNamespaces()
p[vapply(p, function(p) fun %in% ls(envir = asNamespace(p)), FUN.VALUE = FALSE)]
#[1] "car"  "lme4"
```