# Error: row_number() should only be called in a data context

Tags: r, row

I have used this string of code in R for months and months.  Just now running it it came up with an error where I haven't before. Here is the code:
dat <- dat %>%
mutate(row = row_number())
Here is the error:
Error: row_number() should only be called in a data context
The data frame "dat" is a normal data frame of 8 columns and 400,000 rows.

Comment: Try `dat <- dat %>% dplyr::mutate(row = row_number())`

Comment: Almost certainly you loaded `plyr` (or loaded another package that loaded `plyr`) and the old `plyr::mutate` function is masking `dplyr::mutate`. To solve the problem in the moment you can restart R, or [unload `plyr`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6979989/903061), or specify `dplyr::mutate`, or use the `conflicted` package to handle name conflicts. In the future be careful to not load `plyr` after `dplyr`. (A fairly big warning prints if you do - look out for it.)

Comment: Thank you so much!!