# Understanding element wise clearing of R's workspace

Tags: r, workspace

I am trying to find a way to clear the workspace in R using lists.

According to the documentation, I could simply create a vector with all my workspace objects: `WS=c(ls())`. But nothing happens when I try element wise deletion with `rm(c(ls())` or `rm(WS)`.

I know I can use the command `rm(list=ls())`. I am just trying to figure how R works. Where did I err in my thinking in applying the `rm()` function on a vector with the list of the objects?

---

Specifically, I'm trying to create a function similar to the `clc` function in MATLAB, but I am having trouble getting it to work. Here's the function that I've written:

```
clc <- function() { rm(list = ls()) }
```

Comment: Also discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536036/rmlist-ls-doesnt-completely-clear-the-workspace

Comment: I am trying to find a simple way of clearing the WS in Rstudio. I tried creating a function, similar to the `clc` function in matlab to clear the workspace but I am having trouble getting it to work. It seems, I can't create a function in R without an input. clc=function(){
  rm(list=ls())
}

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From `?rm`, "Details" section:

> Earlier versions of R incorrectly claimed that supplying a character vector in ... removed the objects named in the character vector, but it removed the character vector. Use the list argument to specify objects via a character vector.

Your attempt should have been:

```
rm(list = WS)
```

***HOWEVER***, this will still leave you with an object (a character vector) named "WS" in your workspace since that was created *after* you called `WS <- c(ls())`. To actually get rid of the "WS" object, you would have had to use `rm(WS, list = WS)`. :-)

---

How does it work? If you look at the code for `rm`, the first few lines of the function captures any individual objects that have been specified, whether quoted or unquoted. Towards the end of the function, you will find the line `list <- .Primitive("c")(list, names)` which basically creates a character vector of all of the objects individually named and any objects in the character vector supplied to the "list" argument.

---

#### Update

Based on your comment, it sounds like you're trying to write a function like:

```
.clc <- function() {
 rm(list = ls(.GlobalEnv), envir = .GlobalEnv)
}
```

I think it's a little bit of a dangerous function, but let's test it out:

```
ls()
# character(0)
for (i in 1:5) assign(letters[i], i)
ls()
# [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "i"
.clc() 

ls()
# character(0)
```

***Note***: FYI, I've named the function `.clc` (with a dot) so that it doesn't get removed when the function is run. If you wanted to write a version of the function without the `.`, you would probably do better to put the function in a package and load that at startup to have the function available.

Comment: to really grab everything, you will need to set `all=TRUE` inside `ls()` otherwise you will leave behind any object that starts with a `.dot`

Comment: You can remove the function without issue.  The current instantion of it will execute without problem but it will be removed from memory

Comment: I'm new to R, but one of the first things I've done is create a custom package for all of the things that I find handy (cls/clr being the first two). It doesn't appear that there is a need to ignore "." prefixed functions/data as the library will still be loaded after the workspace is cleared.

Comment: @SnOrfus, yes, that's true for a package but not for a function created in a session.