# rm() doesn't seem to empty my R workspace

Tags: r

I'm trying to clear my R workspace. Nothing I've found in any thread seems to work - and I've been googling and trying solutions for hours now :(

When I open R and type `ls`, the console displays all the code from a previous session:

```
function (name, pos = -1L, envir = as.environment(pos), all.names = FALSE, 
    pattern) 
{
    if (!missing(name)) {
        nameValue <- try(name, silent = TRUE)
        if (identical(class(nameValue), "try-error")) {
            name <- substitute(name)
            if (!is.character(name)) 
                name <- deparse(name)
            warning(gettextf("%s converted to character string", 
                sQuote(name)), domain = NA)
            pos <- name
        }
        else pos <- nameValue
    }
    all.names <- .Internal(ls(envir, all.names))
    if (!missing(pattern)) {
        if ((ll <- length(grep("[", pattern, fixed = TRUE))) && 
            ll != length(grep("]", pattern, fixed = TRUE))) {
            if (pattern == "[") {
                pattern <- "\\["
                warning("replaced regular expression pattern '[' by  '\\\\['")
            }
            else if (length(grep("[^\\\\]\\[<-", pattern))) {
                pattern <- sub("\\[<-", "\\\\\\[<-", pattern)
                warning("replaced '[<-' by '\\\\[<-' in regular expression pattern")
            }
        }
        grep(pattern, all.names, value = TRUE)
    }
    else all.names
}
<bytecode: 0x2974f38>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

If I type `rm(list=ls())` and then type `ls` again, I get the exact same response - i.e., the code from the previous session hasn't been removed.

By the way, I'm typing `ls` *without* the parentheses. Typing `ls()` with parentheses returns `character(0)`.

I've also tried clearing the environment via RStudio, and even deleting the ~/.Rdata file. Nothing will clear this workspace. Every time I restart R and type `ls`, all the old code is still there.

I've already tried the tips in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536036/rmlist-ls-doesnt-completely-clear-the-workspace), and they don't work for me.

Any idea why this might be happening? Thanks!

Comment: It's not very clear what you're trying to do.  `rm(list=ls())` removes all the *objects* in the global environment.  What do you mean by *the code is still there*?  Please show an example if you can

Comment: You're typing `ls()` to list the objects, and not `ls` (without `()`), is that correct?

Comment: when you talk about code, are you talking about the code commands you've run in the history?

Comment: @MatthewLundberg, I'm typing `ls` _without_ the parentheses. Typing `ls()` with parentheses returns `character(0)`

Comment: Perhaps you have replace the standard R `ls`-function with something else. Now type `rm(ls)`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you are seeing is the source code for the `ls` function. When you enter a function name without the parentheses, you'll see the complete source code for that function (provided that function is in one of the packages attached to the search path, or in the global environment).

When you see `character(0)` as the result of calling `ls()`, that means that there are no objects in the global environment. The base package, where `ls` calls home, is different from the global environment, and objects there cannot be removed.

When `character(0)` is the result of `ls()` after you call `rm(list=ls())`, you have successfully cleared the objects in the global environment.

Comment: Wow. I feel _fantastically_ stupid. If there's no way to delete this thread, I guess I'll live with this shame forever.

Comment: @BenThomas - It's not a bad question at all.  I bet quite a few people get confused by that.  Hopefully the question  will be useful for future SO'ers

Comment: @Ben Thomas- very useful question. I'm starting with R ( with 30 years of Matlab experience ) and I had the same query and found my answer here. Good question and good answer.